# Plot the time evolution of a variable in a fixed point of a netcdf file using python

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a netcdf file with the time-dependent distribution of the velocity field in a tank of water. I roughly know how to plot the big picture of the velocity field in a specific time step, but I would like to plot the change in time of the velocity variables (u,v,w) in a fixed point of space.

Everything using python.

Comment: Where's your existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Once you loaded the data this is very easy using slicing. For example, with a NetCDF data file from our model as an example:

Output of `ncdump -h`:

```
netcdf w.xz {  
dimensions:  
    x = 1024 ;  
    y = 1 ;  
    zh = 512 ;  
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (81 currently)  
variables:  
    float time(time) ;  
        string time:units = "Seconds since start of experiment" ;  
    float x(x) ;  
    float y(y) ;  
    float zh(zh) ;  
    float w(time, zh, x, y) ;  
}
```

If you load both the time and velocity variables as:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4

f    = nc4.Dataset('w.xz.nc')
time = f.variables['time'][:]
w    = f.variables['w'][:,:,:,:]   # dimensions: time,z,x,y
```

You can take a time slice at e.g. location `z,x,y = index{10,5,1}`

```
k = 10; i = 5; j = 1
data = w[:,k,i,j]
```

Or plot it as:

```
pl.plot(time, w[:,k,i,j])
```